# Laravel mail not sending right data

Tags: laravel, email

I am trying to send a message from a web page using laravel.

Below is my form

`App/Mail/contact.php`:

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;


class contact extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public  $details;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details)
    {
        //
        $this->details=$details;
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope
     */
    public function envelope()
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: 'Contact',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content
     */
    public function content()
    {
        return new Content(
            view: 'emails.contact',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the attachments for the message.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attachments()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

`MailSenderController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use redirect
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
//import mail support
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
//import mailsender
use App\Mail\contact;
use Session;


class MailSenderController extends Controller
{
    //
           function sendMail(Request $request){
        //Validate Here
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
            'message'=>'required'
        ]);

        //Collect Posted data;
         $details=[
        'name'=>$request->name,
        'email'=>$request->email,
        'subject'=>'Testing Variable',
        'message'=>$request->message,

        ];
        //send mail
        Mail::to('mymail@gmail.com')->send(new contact($details));
           //redirect to contact with success message
         return redirect(url()->previous() .'#form5-d')
                 ->with("message","Message sent");

    }

}
```

and here is my the body of my contact view

```html
 <body>
    <h1 class="text-primary">Thank's for reaching out to me!</h1>
<p>
<br>
Hello,
<br>
{{ $details->name }} just sent you a message from your Portfolio website<br>
<br>
<h3>From</h3>{{$name }}
<h3>Subject</h3>{{$details['subject']}}
<br>
<h3>Email</h3> {{$details['email']}}
<br>
<h3>Message</h3>
{{$details['message']}} <br>
</body>
```

The mail get delivered to the email address but in my mail, I get

> {{ $details->name }} just sent you a message from your Portfolio website
>
> From
> {{$name }}
> Subject
> {{$details['subject']}}
> Email
> {{$details['email']}}
> Message
> {{$details['message']}}

Comment: Is your view saved as`<name>.blade.php`?

Comment: 'Separately, probably remove the 'spurious apo'strophe.

Answer (score 0):

youn need to return $details in method attachment in App/Mail/contact.php

Comment: thanks alot...

i  didnt save the mail template as .blade.php. after making that correction, everything worked fine